# Definition of skew-adjoint operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, self-adjoint-operators, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $n\in\mathbb N$. It is customary to call an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ *self-adjoint* iff the (complex conjugate of the) transpose of $A$ is equal to $A$, and to call $A$ *skew-adjoint* iff the (complex conjugate of the) transpose of $A$ is equal to $-A$.

---

Now let's go to the infinite-dimensional case: Let $H$ be a Hilbert space over $\mathbb C$ with the inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ and let $T:D(T)\to H$ be a linear operator, where $D(T)\subset H$ is dense.

It is customary to call $T$ *self-adjoint* iff

1. $\langle Tx, y\rangle = \langle x, Ty\rangle$ for all $x,y\in D(T)$; and
2. $\{y\in H:\text{ The operator }T_y:D(T)\to\mathbb C, x\mapsto \langle Tx, y\rangle\text{ is bounded}\} = D(T)$.

---

**My question.** Is there an analogous notion for skew-adjoint?

**My idea.** An operator $T$ is called *skew-adjoint* iff $i T$ is self-adjoint.

Comment: Your idea is exactly the common definition. Equivalently, it is an operator with $T^\ast=-T$, where one has to take proper care of the domains (as you did in the definition of self-adjoint operator).